# How to use ImageMagick getImagePixelColor as exec command?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I try to get the pixel at a coordinate in a image. I have the following working in PHP, but unfortunately my current setup only allows to use EXEC access to ImageMagick.

How would these lines look as an exec command

```
$img = new Imagick('test2.jpg');
$pixel = $img->getImagePixelColor(10, 10);
$target = $pixel->getColorAsString();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CLI command, user the [`-format`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#format_identify_) operator to read color information.

```
convert test2.jpg -format '%[pixel:p{10,10}]' info:-
```

See [Accessing Pixels](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) section in the FX document, and [Format & Print Image Properties](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

An explanation:

```
%[pixel:        ] <= Evaluate a pixel color by FX expression
        p{10,10}  <= An FX expression to specify an absolute position
```

You can also simplify the above example by using the `identify` utility

```
identify -format '%[pixel:p{10,10}]' test2.jpg
```